# Show only records with multiple indicators

Tags: report, crosstab, cognos

I am developing a report using Cognos Report Studio and I need a way to filter the data to only show when an ID has multiple indicators in the indicator field.

The problem I am getting is the indicator field has values of A-F but for every time they chose A it counts it as 1. So I cannot simply filter by saying where Indicator > 1.

Preferably I would like to have a crosstab with IDs in the rows and the different indicators in the columns.

example:

```
     IND A  IND B  IND C
ID 1   20
ID 2   5      10
ID 3   1
ID 4          40    1000
```

in the case above I would only want to show ID 2 and ID 4

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the raw data looks like in tabular form? That would help to understand the data domain so the correct answer can be determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add additional field with expression like

```
count([Indicator] for [Your ID field])
```

And filter for values of this field > 1

Comment: that will just count all the indicators, so line 2 in my example will be 15.

Comment: count(distinct [Indicator] for [Your ID field])